# frame buffer size changes but viewport cannot be set

Tags: c++, opengl

Simple and short question but I don't know why it is not working. When I call glViewport in the window frame buffer callback nothing changes. Error code is 1282 (0x502). I already googled and found no helpful article. Some said I should use glScissor in addition but does not work either.

**Here an MCVE with an oscillating quad for visualization:**

```
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include "glm/vec3.hpp"

#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <wingdi.h>

int createShaders() {
    const char* vertex = R"(
        #version 330 core

        layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

        uniform float scale;

        void main() {
            gl_Position =  vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1.0) * vec4(vec3(scale), 1.0f);
        }
    )";

    const char* fragment = R"(
        #version 330 core

        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        }
    )";

    int vertexID, fragmentID, pid;

    vertexID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    const GLchar* source = (const GLchar*)vertex;
    glShaderSource(vertexID, 1, &source, 0);

    glCompileShader(vertexID);

    int isCompiled = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled);
    if (isCompiled == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int maxLength = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(vertexID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        char* infoLog = new char[maxLength];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexID, maxLength, &maxLength, infoLog);
        std::cout << infoLog << std::endl;

        glDeleteShader(vertexID);
        return 0;
    }

    fragmentID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    source = (const GLchar*)fragment;
    glShaderSource(fragmentID, 1, &source, 0);

    glCompileShader(fragmentID);

    glGetShaderiv(fragmentID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled);
    if (isCompiled == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int maxLength = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(fragmentID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        char* infoLog = new char[maxLength];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentID, maxLength, &maxLength, infoLog);
        std::cout << infoLog << std::endl;

        glDeleteShader(fragmentID);
        glDeleteShader(vertexID);

        return 0;
    }

    pid = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(pid, vertexID);
    glAttachShader(pid, fragmentID);

    glLinkProgram(pid);

    int isLinked = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(pid, GL_LINK_STATUS, (int*)&isLinked);
    if (isLinked == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int maxLength = 0;
        glGetProgramiv(pid, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        std::vector<GLchar> infoLog(maxLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(pid, maxLength, &maxLength, &infoLog[0]);

        glDeleteProgram(pid);
        glDeleteShader(vertexID);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentID);

        return 0;
    }

    glDetachShader(pid, vertexID);
    glDetachShader(pid, fragmentID);

    return pid;
}

unsigned int createVertexArray() {
    std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices = {
        glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f)
    };

    unsigned int arrayID, id;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &arrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(arrayID);

    glGenBuffers(1, &id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    return arrayID;
}

int main() {
    if (!glfwInit())
        return 1;

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(960, 520, "MCVE", NULL, NULL);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, [](GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    });

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        return 1;

    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);

    std::thread mainLoopThread([window]() {
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        int shaderID = createShaders();
        int vertexID = createVertexArray();

        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point current = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            std::chrono::microseconds time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(current - start);

            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            
            glUseProgram(shaderID);
            float s = sin(time.count() / 1000000.0f * 2.0f);
            glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderID, "scale"), s);
            glBindVertexArray(vertexID);
            glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
            
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        }
    });

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        glfwWaitEvents();

    mainLoopThread.join();

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to call a OpenGL instruction without a current [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context).
The callback is executed in the main thread. However the OpenGL Context is not current in the main thread. The OpenGL context is current in the `mainLoopThread` thread.
Set a state in the callback function (e.g. `std::atomic<bool>`) and invoke `glViewport` in the `mainLoopThread` thread, once the state is set.